# How can I do some kind of upsert within Postgres 9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have a simple table:

```
NAME    | TIMESTAMP | AMOUNT
--------------------------
Name1   | 123       | 1
Name2   | 123       | 15
Name3   | 124       | 3
Name4   | 125       | 1
```

And so on.
Now I get a new record. If the name and the timestamp is equal, I want the amount to be increased by the amount of the new record, otherwise the new record should be inserted.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO test.data (NAME, TIMESTAMP, AMOUNT) values ('Name1', 123, 4) 
IF not EXIST; OTHERWISE UPDATE test.data set AMOUNT + NEWAMOUNT where TIMESTAMP = oldTimestamp and NAME = oldName
```

Is this somehow possible with one simple sql query using Postgres  9.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the new [`on conflict`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause:

```
INSERT INTO test.data (NAME, TIMESTAMP, AMOUNT) 
values ('Name1', 123, 4) 
on conflict (name, timestamp) 
  do update 
    set AMOUNT + excluded.NEWAMOUNT
```

This requires that you have a unique constraint (or index) defined on `(name, timestamp)`

If you don't want to make `(name, timestamp)` unique, you *could* use a writeable CTE:

```
with new_values (name, timestamp, amount) as (
  values ('Name1', 123, 4)
), changed as (
  update data 
     set amount = amount + t.amount
  from new_values nv 
   where data.name = nv.name
     and data.timestamp = nv.timestamp
  returning *
)
insert into data (name, timestamp, amount)
select name, timestamp, amount
from new_values
where not exists (select 1 from changed);
```

Note that (unlike the `on conflict` solution) this is not safe against concurrent updates and you might have race conditions

Comment: Actually, neither name nor timestamp are unique. The both in conjunction are unique.. There's also a ID within the table which is the actual primary key..

Comment: @Christian: given the way you work with name, timestamp you do consider it unique though.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but as you see within the example, NAME as well as TIMESTAMP can (and will) occur a lot of times. It's actually a rollup table saying: The sensor with the name bla was active at TIMESTAMP with AMOUNT instances

Comment: @Christian:in your example data the _combination_ of `(name, timestamp)` **is** unique

Comment: ok, you are right man. I'll change my db design so that I have a unique constraint over name, timestamp in conjunction. Thanks mate.

Comment: could you maybe also explain where this exclude.NEWAMOUNT is coming from? This actually should be a reference to the "new" amount coming into the INSERT query.

Comment: The `excluded` is the value that was not inserted. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Answer (score 3):

```
with t as (
  update test.data set 
    AMOUNT = AMOUNT + 4 
  where 
    NAME = 'Name1' and TIMESTAMP = 123 
  returning 
    *) -- In the t we have list of updated rows (if any)

insert into test.data(NAME, TIMESTAMP, AMOUMT)
  select 'Name1', 123, 4
  where not exists (select * from t); -- Insert new row in rows was not updated
```